# Problem calling linux C code from FIQ handler

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm working on an armv6 core and have an FIQ hander that works great when I do all of my work in it.  However I need to branch to some additional code that's too large for the FIQ memory area.

The FIQ handler gets copied from fiq_start to fiq_end to 0xFFFF001C when registered

```
static void test_fiq_handler(void)
{
    asm volatile("\
    .global fiq_start\n\
    fiq_start:");

    // clear gpio irq
    asm("ldr r10, GPIO_BASE_ISR");
    asm("ldr r9, [r10]");
    asm("orr r9, #0x04");
    asm("str r9, [r10]");

    // clear force register
    asm("ldr r10, AVIC_BASE_INTFRCH");
    asm("ldr r9, [r10]");
    asm("mov r9, #0");
    asm("str r9, [r10]");

    // prepare branch register
    asm("   ldr r11,    fiq_handler");

    // save all registers, build sp and branch to C
    asm("   adr r9, regpool");
    asm("   stmia   r9, {r0 - r8, r14}");
    asm("   adr sp, fiq_sp");
    asm("   ldr sp, [sp]");
    asm("   add lr, pc,#4");
    asm("   mov pc, r11");

#if 0
    asm("ldr r10, IOMUX_ADDR12");
    asm("ldr r9, [r10]");
    asm("orr r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
    asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
    asm("bic r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
    asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
#endif

    asm("   adr r9, regpool");
    asm("   ldmia   r9, {r0 - r8, r14}");

   // return
    asm("subs pc, r14, #4");

    asm("IOMUX_ADDR12:      .word 0xFC2A4000");
    asm("AVIC_BASE_INTCNTL: .word 0xFC400000");
    asm("AVIC_BASE_INTENNUM:    .word 0xFC400008");
    asm("AVIC_BASE_INTDISNUM:   .word 0xFC40000C");
    asm("AVIC_BASE_FIVECSR: .word 0xFC400044");
    asm("AVIC_BASE_INTFRCH:     .word 0xFC400050");
    asm("GPIO_BASE_ISR:          .word 0xFC2CC018");

    asm(".globl fiq_handler");
    asm("fiq_sp:    .long fiq_stack+120");
    asm("fiq_handler:   .long 0");
    asm("regpool:   .space 40");

    asm(".pool");

    asm(".align 5");
    asm("fiq_stack: .space 124");

    asm(".global fiq_end");
    asm("fiq_end:");
}
```

fiq_hander gets set to the following function:

```
static void fiq_flip_pins(void)
{
    asm("ldr r10, IOMUX_ADDR12_k");
    asm("ldr r9, [r10]");
    asm("orr r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
    asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
    asm("bic r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
    asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
    asm("IOMUX_ADDR12_k:    .word 0xFC2A4000");
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(fiq_flip_pins);
```

I know that since the FIQ handler operates outside of any normal kernel API's and that it is a rather high priority interrupt I must ensure that whatever I call is already swapped into memory.  I do this by having the fiq_flip_pins function defined in the monolithic kernel and not as a module which gets vmalloc.

If I don't branch to the fiq_flip_pins function, and instead do the work in the test_fiq_handler function everything works as expected.  It's the branching that's causing me problems at the moment.  Right after branching I get a kernel panic about a paging request.  I don't understand why I'm getting the paging request.

fiq_flip_pins is in the kernel at:
c00307ec t fiq_flip_pins

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 736e6f63
pgd = c3dd0000
[736e6f63] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT
Modules linked in: hello_1
CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.31-207-g7286c01-svn4 #122)
PC is at strnlen+0x10/0x28
LR is at string+0x38/0xcc
pc : [<c016b004>]    lr : [<c016c754>]    psr: a00001d3
sp : c3817ea0  ip : 736e6f63  fp : 00000400
r10: c03cab5c  r9 : c0339ae0  r8 : 736e6f63
r7 : c03caf5c  r6 : c03cab6b  r5 : ffffffff  r4 : 00000000
r3 : 00000004  r2 : 00000000  r1 : ffffffff  r0 : 736e6f63
Flags: NzCv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 00c5387d  Table: 83dd0008  DAC: 00000015
Process sh (pid: 1663, stack limit = 0xc3816268)
Stack: (0xc3817ea0 to 0xc3818000)
```

Since there are no API calls in my code I have to assume that something is going wrong in the C call and back.  Any help solving this is appreciated.

Here's the assembly with comments for fiq_flip_pins:

```
static void fiq_flip_pins(void)
{
    asm("ldr r10, IOMUX_ADDR12_k");
   0:   e59fa010    ldr sl, [pc, #16]   ; 18 <IOMUX_ADDR12_k>
    asm("ldr r9, [r10]");
   4:   e59a9000    ldr r9, [sl]
    asm("orr r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
   8:   e3899008    orr r9, r9, #8  ; 0x8
    asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
   c:   e58a9000    str r9, [sl]
    asm("bic r9, #0x08                        @ top/vertex LED");
  10:   e3c99008    bic r9, r9, #8  ; 0x8
     asm("str r9,[r10]                            @turn on LED");
  14:   e58a9000    str r9, [sl]

00000018 <IOMUX_ADDR12_k>:
  18:   fc2a4000    .word   0xfc2a4000
    asm("IOMUX_ADDR12_k:    .word 0xFC2A4000");
}
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Comment: It is completely acceptable to have a single branch instruction to the actual interrupt handler, as for the other exception types. The special arrangement of placing the FIQ at the end so the entire handler can be placed there is for the benefit of high-frequency interrupt handlers where the number of cycles actually counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it looks like `fiq_handler` points to address `0`, not `fiq_flip_pins`:

```
asm("fiq_handler:   .long 0");
```

Another possible problem (assuming that there's code that fixes up the `fiq_handler` pointer when `fiq_test` is copied over) is that you have this at the end of `fiq_flip_pins`:

```
asm("IOMUX_ADDR12_k:    .word 0xFC2A4000");
```

You'll need to have some code that jumps over that data or have your own return sequence for `fiq_flip_pins` prior to that data word, otherwise the CPU will try to execute whatever opcode 0xFC2A4000 is, and I imagine it's not likely to be something benign.

Comment: fiq_handler gets set to fiq_flip_pins when I setup the FIQ.

I just added the assembly for fiq_flip_pins to my main post, it was too many characters to put here.

Comment: Michael, I misunderstood what you were saying.  I added a "bx lr" call to before the IOMUX_ADDR12_k value and it's working.  Something so simple...Thank you very much!